# when exporting from highcharts, the self added image turned to be a square with "?", why?

Tags: highcharts

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w9vq7p3d/

In the links above, It add a image which url is "https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png". and it works well, when exporting, I can get the correct output with this image.
[image]
but when I move the same png to my site, such as "https://www.example.com/sun.png". when exporting, the sun.png turned to be a square with "?".
[image]

Why, how to fix it?

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this,
          renderer = chart.renderer,
          width = 30;

        // Delete groups
        if (chart.customImgGroup) {
          chart.customImgGroup.destroy();
        }

        // Create groups
        chart.customImgGroup = renderer.g('customImgGroup').add();

        // Render texts
 chart.renderer.image('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',chart.plotLeft + chart.plotSizeX - width, 50, width, 30)
        .add(chart.customImgGroup);
      }
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
      marker: {
        radius: 5,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true,
            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
          }
        }
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Female',
    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
    data: [
      [161.2, 51.6],
      [167.5, 59.0],
      [159.5, 49.2],
      [157.0, 63.0],
      [155.8, 53.6],
      [170.0, 59.0],
      [159.1, 47.6],
      [166.0, 69.8],
      [176.2, 66.8],
      [160.2, 75.2],
      [172.5, 55.2],
      [170.9, 54.2],
      [172.9, 62.5],
      [153.4, 42.0],
      [160.0, 50.0],
      [147.2, 49.8],
      [168.2, 49.2],
      [175.0, 73.2],
      [157.0, 47.8],
      [167.6, 68.8],
      [159.5, 50.6],
      [175.0, 82.5],
      [166.8, 57.2],
      [176.5, 87.8],
      [170.2, 72.8],
      [174.0, 54.5],
      [173.0, 59.8],
      [179.9, 67.3],
      [170.5, 67.8],
      [160.0, 47.0],
      [154.4, 46.2],
      [162.0, 55.0],
      [176.5, 83.0],
      [160.0, 54.4],
      [152.0, 45.8],
      [162.1, 53.6],
      [170.0, 73.2],
      [160.2, 52.1],
      [161.3, 67.9],
      [166.4, 56.6],
      [168.9, 62.3],
      [163.8, 58.5],
      [167.6, 54.5],
      [160.0, 50.2],
      [161.3, 60.3],
      [167.6, 58.3],
      [165.1, 56.2],
      [160.0, 50.2],
      [170.0, 72.9],
      [157.5, 59.8],
      [167.6, 61.0],
      [160.7, 69.1],
      [163.2, 55.9],
      [152.4, 46.5],
      [157.5, 54.3],
      [168.3, 54.8],
      [180.3, 60.7],
      [165.5, 60.0],
      [165.0, 62.0],
      [164.5, 60.3],
      [156.0, 52.7],
      [160.0, 74.3],
      [163.0, 62.0],
      [165.7, 73.1],
      [161.0, 80.0],
      [162.0, 54.7],
      [166.0, 53.2],
      [174.0, 75.7],
      [172.7, 61.1],
      [167.6, 55.7],
      [151.1, 48.7],
      [164.5, 52.3],
      [163.5, 50.0],
      [152.0, 59.3],
      [169.0, 62.5],
      [164.0, 55.7],
      [161.2, 54.8],
      [155.0, 45.9],
      [170.0, 70.6],
      [176.2, 67.2],
      [170.0, 69.4],
      [162.5, 58.2],
      [170.3, 64.8],
      [164.1, 71.6],
      [169.5, 52.8],
      [163.2, 59.8],
      [154.5, 49.0],
      [159.8, 50.0],
      [173.2, 69.2],
      [170.0, 55.9],
      [161.4, 63.4],
      [169.0, 58.2],
      [166.2, 58.6],
      [159.4, 45.7],
      [162.5, 52.2],
      [159.0, 48.6],
      [162.8, 57.8],
      [159.0, 55.6],
      [179.8, 66.8],
      [162.9, 59.4],
      [161.0, 53.6],
      [151.1, 73.2],
      [168.2, 53.4],
      [168.9, 69.0],
      [173.2, 58.4],
      [171.8, 56.2],
      [178.0, 70.6],
      [164.3, 59.8],
      [163.0, 72.0],
      [168.5, 65.2],
      [166.8, 56.6],
      [172.7, 105.2],
      [163.5, 51.8],
      [169.4, 63.4],
      [167.8, 59.0],
      [159.5, 47.6],
      [167.6, 63.0],
      [161.2, 55.2],
      [160.0, 45.0],
      [163.2, 54.0],
      [162.2, 50.2],
      [161.3, 60.2],
      [149.5, 44.8],
      [157.5, 58.8],
      [163.2, 56.4],
      [172.7, 62.0],
      [155.0, 49.2],
      [156.5, 67.2],
      [164.0, 53.8],
      [160.9, 54.4],
      [162.8, 58.0],
      [167.0, 59.8],
      [160.0, 54.8],
      [160.0, 43.2],
      [168.9, 60.5],
      [158.2, 46.4],
      [156.0, 64.4],
      [160.0, 48.8],
      [167.1, 62.2],
      [158.0, 55.5],
      [167.6, 57.8],
      [156.0, 54.6],
      [162.1, 59.2],
      [173.4, 52.7],
      [159.8, 53.2],
      [170.5, 64.5],
      [159.2, 51.8],
      [157.5, 56.0],
      [161.3, 63.6],
      [162.6, 63.2],
      [160.0, 59.5],
      [168.9, 56.8],
      [165.1, 64.1],
      [162.6, 50.0],
      [165.1, 72.3],
      [166.4, 55.0],
      [160.0, 55.9],
      [152.4, 60.4],
      [170.2, 69.1],
      [162.6, 84.5],
      [170.2, 55.9],
      [158.8, 55.5],
      [172.7, 69.5],
      [167.6, 76.4],
      [162.6, 61.4],
      [167.6, 65.9],
      [156.2, 58.6],
      [175.2, 66.8],
      [172.1, 56.6],
      [162.6, 58.6],
      [160.0, 55.9],
      [165.1, 59.1],
      [182.9, 81.8],
      [166.4, 70.7],
      [165.1, 56.8],
      [177.8, 60.0],
      [165.1, 58.2],
      [175.3, 72.7],
      [154.9, 54.1],
      [158.8, 49.1],
      [172.7, 75.9],
      [168.9, 55.0],
      [161.3, 57.3],
      [167.6, 55.0],
      [165.1, 65.5],
      [175.3, 65.5],
      [157.5, 48.6],
      [163.8, 58.6],
      [167.6, 63.6],
      [165.1, 55.2],
      [165.1, 62.7],
      [168.9, 56.6],
      [162.6, 53.9],
      [164.5, 63.2],
      [176.5, 73.6],
      [168.9, 62.0],
      [175.3, 63.6],
      [159.4, 53.2],
      [160.0, 53.4],
      [170.2, 55.0],
      [162.6, 70.5],
      [167.6, 54.5],
      [162.6, 54.5],
      [160.7, 55.9],
      [160.0, 59.0],
      [157.5, 63.6],
      [162.6, 54.5],
      [152.4, 47.3],
      [170.2, 67.7],
      [165.1, 80.9],
      [172.7, 70.5],
      [165.1, 60.9],
      [170.2, 63.6],
      [170.2, 54.5],
      [170.2, 59.1],
      [161.3, 70.5],
      [167.6, 52.7],
      [167.6, 62.7],
      [165.1, 86.3],
      [162.6, 66.4],
      [152.4, 67.3],
      [168.9, 63.0],
      [170.2, 73.6],
      [175.2, 62.3],
      [175.2, 57.7],
      [160.0, 55.4],
      [165.1, 104.1],
      [174.0, 55.5],
      [170.2, 77.3],
      [160.0, 80.5],
      [167.6, 64.5],
      [167.6, 72.3],
      [167.6, 61.4],
      [154.9, 58.2],
      [162.6, 81.8],
      [175.3, 63.6],
      [171.4, 53.4],
      [157.5, 54.5],
      [165.1, 53.6],
      [160.0, 60.0],
      [174.0, 73.6],
      [162.6, 61.4],
      [174.0, 55.5],
      [162.6, 63.6],
      [161.3, 60.9],
      [156.2, 60.0],
      [149.9, 46.8],
      [169.5, 57.3],
      [160.0, 64.1],
      [175.3, 63.6],
      [169.5, 67.3],
      [160.0, 75.5],
      [172.7, 68.2],
      [162.6, 61.4],
      [157.5, 76.8],
      [176.5, 71.8],
      [164.4, 55.5],
      [160.7, 48.6],
      [174.0, 66.4],
      [163.8, 67.3]
    ]

  }, {
    name: 'Male',
    color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
    data: [
      [174.0, 65.6],
      [175.3, 71.8],
      [193.5, 80.7],
      [186.5, 72.6],
      [187.2, 78.8],
      [181.5, 74.8],
      [184.0, 86.4],
      [184.5, 78.4],
      [175.0, 62.0],
      [184.0, 81.6],
      [180.0, 76.6],
      [177.8, 83.6],
      [192.0, 90.0],
      [176.0, 74.6],
      [174.0, 71.0],
      [184.0, 79.6],
      [192.7, 93.8],
      [171.5, 70.0],
      [173.0, 72.4],
      [176.0, 85.9],
      [176.0, 78.8],
      [180.5, 77.8],
      [172.7, 66.2],
      [176.0, 86.4],
      [173.5, 81.8],
      [178.0, 89.6],
      [180.3, 82.8],
      [180.3, 76.4],
      [164.5, 63.2],
      [173.0, 60.9],
      [183.5, 74.8],
      [175.5, 70.0],
      [188.0, 72.4],
      [189.2, 84.1],
      [172.8, 69.1],
      [170.0, 59.5],
      [182.0, 67.2],
      [170.0, 61.3],
      [177.8, 68.6],
      [184.2, 80.1],
      [186.7, 87.8],
      [171.4, 84.7],
      [172.7, 73.4],
      [175.3, 72.1],
      [180.3, 82.6],
      [182.9, 88.7],
      [188.0, 84.1],
      [177.2, 94.1],
      [172.1, 74.9],
      [167.0, 59.1],
      [169.5, 75.6],
      [174.0, 86.2],
      [172.7, 75.3],
      [182.2, 87.1],
      [164.1, 55.2],
      [163.0, 57.0],
      [171.5, 61.4],
      [184.2, 76.8],
      [174.0, 86.8],
      [174.0, 72.2],
      [177.0, 71.6],
      [186.0, 84.8],
      [167.0, 68.2],
      [171.8, 66.1],
      [182.0, 72.0],
      [167.0, 64.6],
      [177.8, 74.8],
      [164.5, 70.0],
      [192.0, 101.6],
      [175.5, 63.2],
      [171.2, 79.1],
      [181.6, 78.9],
      [167.4, 67.7],
      [181.1, 66.0],
      [177.0, 68.2],
      [174.5, 63.9],
      [177.5, 72.0],
      [170.5, 56.8],
      [182.4, 74.5],
      [197.1, 90.9],
      [180.1, 93.0],
      [175.5, 80.9],
      [180.6, 72.7],
      [184.4, 68.0],
      [175.5, 70.9],
      [180.6, 72.5],
      [177.0, 72.5],
      [177.1, 83.4],
      [181.6, 75.5],
      [176.5, 73.0],
      [175.0, 70.2],
      [174.0, 73.4],
      [165.1, 70.5],
      [177.0, 68.9],
      [192.0, 102.3],
      [176.5, 68.4],
      [169.4, 65.9],
      [182.1, 75.7],
      [179.8, 84.5],
      [175.3, 87.7],
      [184.9, 86.4],
      [177.3, 73.2],
      [167.4, 53.9],
      [178.1, 72.0],
      [168.9, 55.5],
      [157.2, 58.4],
      [180.3, 83.2],
      [170.2, 72.7],
      [177.8, 64.1],
      [172.7, 72.3],
      [165.1, 65.0],
      [186.7, 86.4],
      [165.1, 65.0],
      [174.0, 88.6],
      [175.3, 84.1],
      [185.4, 66.8],
      [177.8, 75.5],
      [180.3, 93.2],
      [180.3, 82.7],
      [177.8, 58.0],
      [177.8, 79.5],
      [177.8, 78.6],
      [177.8, 71.8],
      [177.8, 116.4],
      [163.8, 72.2],
      [188.0, 83.6],
      [198.1, 85.5],
      [175.3, 90.9],
      [166.4, 85.9],
      [190.5, 89.1],
      [166.4, 75.0],
      [177.8, 77.7],
      [179.7, 86.4],
      [172.7, 90.9],
      [190.5, 73.6],
      [185.4, 76.4],
      [168.9, 69.1],
      [167.6, 84.5],
      [175.3, 64.5],
      [170.2, 69.1],
      [190.5, 108.6],
      [177.8, 86.4],
      [190.5, 80.9],
      [177.8, 87.7],
      [184.2, 94.5],
      [176.5, 80.2],
      [177.8, 72.0],
      [180.3, 71.4],
      [171.4, 72.7],
      [172.7, 84.1],
      [172.7, 76.8],
      [177.8, 63.6],
      [177.8, 80.9],
      [182.9, 80.9],
      [170.2, 85.5],
      [167.6, 68.6],
      [175.3, 67.7],
      [165.1, 66.4],
      [185.4, 102.3],
      [181.6, 70.5],
      [172.7, 95.9],
      [190.5, 84.1],
      [179.1, 87.3],
      [175.3, 71.8],
      [170.2, 65.9],
      [193.0, 95.9],
      [171.4, 91.4],
      [177.8, 81.8],
      [177.8, 96.8],
      [167.6, 69.1],
      [167.6, 82.7],
      [180.3, 75.5],
      [182.9, 79.5],
      [176.5, 73.6],
      [186.7, 91.8],
      [188.0, 84.1],
      [188.0, 85.9],
      [177.8, 81.8],
      [174.0, 82.5],
      [177.8, 80.5],
      [171.4, 70.0],
      [185.4, 81.8],
      [185.4, 84.1],
      [188.0, 90.5],
      [188.0, 91.4],
      [182.9, 89.1],
      [176.5, 85.0],
      [175.3, 69.1],
      [175.3, 73.6],
      [188.0, 80.5],
      [188.0, 82.7],
      [175.3, 86.4],
      [170.5, 67.7],
      [179.1, 92.7],
      [177.8, 93.6],
      [175.3, 70.9],
      [182.9, 75.0],
      [170.8, 93.2],
      [188.0, 93.2],
      [180.3, 77.7],
      [177.8, 61.4],
      [185.4, 94.1],
      [168.9, 75.0],
      [185.4, 83.6],
      [180.3, 85.5],
      [174.0, 73.9],
      [167.6, 66.8],
      [182.9, 87.3],
      [160.0, 72.3],
      [180.3, 88.6],
      [167.6, 75.5],
      [186.7, 101.4],
      [175.3, 91.1],
      [175.3, 67.3],
      [175.9, 77.7],
      [175.3, 81.8],
      [179.1, 75.5],
      [181.6, 84.5],
      [177.8, 76.6],
      [182.9, 85.0],
      [177.8, 102.5],
      [184.2, 77.3],
      [179.1, 71.8],
      [176.5, 87.9],
      [188.0, 94.3],
      [174.0, 70.9],
      [167.6, 64.5],
      [170.2, 77.3],
      [167.6, 72.3],
      [188.0, 87.3],
      [174.0, 80.0],
      [176.5, 82.3],
      [180.3, 73.6],
      [167.6, 74.1],
      [188.0, 85.9],
      [180.3, 73.2],
      [167.6, 76.3],
      [183.0, 65.9],
      [183.0, 90.9],
      [179.1, 89.1],
      [170.2, 62.3],
      [177.8, 82.7],
      [179.1, 79.1],
      [190.5, 98.2],
      [177.8, 84.1],
      [180.3, 83.2],
      [180.3, 83.2]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Try using an encoded base64 image: https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: I think it doesn't matter with base64. Because I just download the sun.png and move it to my website. Then error happens.

Comment: The topic was resolved at Highcharts official [forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=49630), try not to duplicate.